# How do I programmatically submit comments?

Tags: drupal, drupal-comments

I am not sure how to do this; I want to manually submit a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Drupal 6, you'll want to take a look at both [comment_form_submit()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--comment--comment.module/function/comment_form_submit/6) and [comment_save()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--comment--comment.module/function/comment_save/6). For Drupal 7, [comment_save()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--comment--comment.module/function/comment_save) is much more of a true API function, so if you are properly preparing your comment, that's all you should need.

Comment: Hi thanks. i have tried in drupal 6. But I need some working examples

Answer (score 0):

```
      $user = user_load(array(uid => $a_uid));
      $forum_comment_fields = array();
      $forum_comment_fields['values']['author']    = $user->name;
      $forum_comment_fields['values']['subject']   = "";
      $forum_comment_fields['values']['comment']   = $comment;
      $forum_comment_fields['values']['op']        = t('Save');
      $forum_comment_fields['values']['nid']       = $nid;
      $forum_comment_fields['values']['date'] = $created;
      comment_form_submit("comment_form", $forum_comment_fields);
```

I think the date is incorrect...